# How can I access the "uploads" folder located on the root folder of my Springboot application with the URL "localhost:8081/uploads"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, path

I can't access the "uploads" folder by typing the URL "localhost:8081/uploads" in the browser. It says about blank, Not found, 404, no static resource.

When I try to access the URL "localhost:8081/uploads", I get the following message from the browser :
{
"type": "about:blank",
"title": "Not Found",
"status": 404,
"detail": "No static resource .",
"instance": "/uploads"
}

I am expecting to see the "uploads" folder content in my browser. Just like when I try to access the "uploads" folder with its absolute path.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I am expecting to see the "uploads" folder content in my browser. Just like when I try to access the "uploads" folder with its absolute path.

You should not expect Spring Boot to serve contents of the folder the app runs in. You'll need set it up manually.
For reference: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364794/is-it-possible-to-enable-directory-listing-in-spring-boot-application), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004870/embedded-tomcat-directory-listing-for-spring-boot-application/46509688#46509688).

Slightly related - Spring Boot does serve contents *some* folders automatically - more details e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393211/how-can-i-serve-static-html-from-spring-boot).